# Not able to type anything in the entry widget, tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The widget is visible with no errors but I'm not able to enter any text in any entry as no cursor appears when I click on the entry (also this whole code is part of a function)(is is just a part of the whole code, all other imports, and mainloop() , etc has been done, also this funtion is used for a button)r , `enter code here`

```
         window2=tk.Tk() 
         window2.title('Password Vault')
         window2.geometry('480x360')
         window2['bg']='black'

         import tkinter as tk

         e3=tk.Entry(window2)#had to do this as it was not recognizing e3,e4,e5 as a tkinter variable
         e4=tk.Entry(window2)
         e5=tk.Entry(window2)
         def clicked_add():
             global e3
             global e4
             global e5
             
             e3=tk.Entry()
             e_3=e3.place(x='110',y='235')
             
             e4=tk.Entry()
             e_4=e4.place(x='110',y='270')
             
             e5=tk.Entry()
             e_5=e5.place(x='110',y='305')
```

Comment: how many mainloop's do you have in your program?

Answer (score 0):

You don't call clicked_add(). And please, import libs on first rows.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little:

```
import tkinter as tk

window2=tk.Tk() 
window2.title('Password Vault')
window2.geometry('480x360')
window2['bg']='black'

e3=tk.Entry()
e_3=e3.place(x='110',y='235')

e4=tk.Entry()
e_4=e4.place(x='110',y='270')

e5=tk.Entry()
e_5=e5.place(x='110',y='305')

window2.mainloop()
```

Like this the code runs fine!

And if you really want the function to be included, run it first!

```
import tkinter as tk

window2=tk.Tk() 
window2.title('Password Vault')
window2.geometry('480x360')
window2['bg']='black'

e3=tk.Entry(window2)#had to do this as it was not recognizing e3,e4,e5 as a tkinter variable
e4=tk.Entry(window2)
e5=tk.Entry(window2)
def clicked_add():
    global e3
    global e4
    global e5
    
    e3=tk.Entry()
    e_3=e3.place(x='110',y='235')
    
    e4=tk.Entry()
    e_4=e4.place(x='110',y='270')
    
    e5=tk.Entry()
    e_5=e5.place(x='110',y='305')

clicked_add()
window2.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't typed clicked_add() at the end. And also you have to grid those entries by typing:

```
e3=tk.Entry(window2).grid(row=1, column=1)
e4=tk.Entry(window2).grid(row=2, column=1)
e5=tk.Entry(window2).grid(row=3, column=1)
```

You can use place() too.
And you have to type `tk.mainloop` at the end.
Done!

Comment: This is just a part,I have used it as a command for a button, all imports are done,ended with window2.mainloop()